# How to foward predicate parameters over akka messages

Tags: scala, akka, parameter-passing, predicate

I need help in forwarding a predicate parameter in Akka messages. I create the predicate when I call a case class in `Master`. I need to forward this parameter to `Worker` node. Here is a part of my implementation.

```
case class select [T: ClassTag] (name: String, cName: String, p: T => Boolean)
case class selectIn [T: ClassTag] (name: String, cName: String, p: T => Boolean)

class Master extends Actor {
    val router: ActorRef = actorOf (RoundRobinPool (4).props(props[Worker]), "router")

    def receive: Receive = {
        case select (name, cName, p) =>
            router ! Broadcast (selectIn (name, cName, p))  // error on p
    }
}

case Worker extends Actor {
    def receive: Receive = {
        case selectIn (name, cName, p) =>
            rMap(name).fetch(cName, p)  // error on p
    }
}

object MasterTest {
    val actor = ActorSystem("ActorSystem").actorOf(Props[Master], "root")

    actor ! select [Int] ("Table1", "Age", x => x < 25)
}
```

`rMap` is a map of `name -> Table`. `fetch` is a function on `Table` to find rows where `cName` satisfies predicate `p`.

I get the following error:

```
type mismatch;
found   : Nothing => Boolean
required: T => Boolean
    router ! Broadcast (selectIn (r.nextInt(randomSeed), name, cName, p))

type mismatch;
found   : Nothing => Boolean
required: T => Boolean
    sender() ! selectReply ("select _" + uc + "_" + tableMap(name), rSeq(tableMap(name)).select(cName, p))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating a `type Predicate [T] = {String, T => Boolean}`.

Then modified the code as:

```
case class select [T: ClassTag] (name: String, p: Predicate[T])
case class selectIn [T: ClassTag] (name: String, p: Predicate[T])

class Master extends Actor {
    val router: ActorRef = actorOf (RoundRobinPool (4).props(props[Worker]), "router")

    def receive: Receive = {
        case select (name, p) =>
            router ! Broadcast (selectIn (name, p))  // error on p
    }
}

case Worker extends Actor {
    def receive: Receive = {
        case selectIn (name, p) =>
            rMap(name).fetch(p._1, p._2)  // error on p
    }
}

object MasterTest {
    val actor = ActorSystem("ActorSystem").actorOf(Props[Master], "root")

    actor ! select [Int] ("Table1", ("Age", x => x < 25))
}
```

Would love to know if there are any other way to solve this.